# powershell calculated property inserting variable before calculation

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have been trying for some time now, to get my $Tenant.Name variable to get inserted as text, instead of as a variable to be grabbed later.

Currently I receive the following output:

| Tenant 1 - AADRoles | Tenant1 - Groups | Tenant 2 - AADRoles | Tenant 2 - Groups |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tenant2Administrator | Tenant2AdminGroup | Tenant2Administrator | Tenant2AdminGroup |

Both Tenants are getting the roles and groups from Tenant 2, which I guess is because the Calculated Property isn't calculating until the end, where it will then use the last value. Am I just a idiot for doing it this way?

What I want to achieve, is find out which permissions and roles the users from MainTenantUsers have in our other Tenants. I thought I would output it by dynamically creating the select-object properties, but it didn't work as well as I hoped.

The SubTenantUsers and MainTenantUsers variables contains information from `Get-AzureADUser`, `Get-AzureADDirectoryRole` and `Get-AzureADGroup` to help figure out which groups and roles the individual users are assigned.

```
# Get a list of tenants the user has access to
$Tenants = Get-AzTenant | Where-Object {$_.TenantId -NotMatch $TenantId}



# Get user Roles in other tenants
foreach ($Tenant in $Tenants) {

    $null = Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $Tenant.Id

    $SubTenantUsers = Get-TenantUsersRolesAndGroups

    foreach ($MainTenantUser in $MainTenantUsers) {
        ### Add tenant to list of tenants the user is a member of
        if ($SubTenantUsers.UserPrincipalName -like ('{0}*' -f $MainTenantUser.UserPrincipalName.Replace("@", "_"))) {
            $MainTenantUser.AccessibleTenants += $Tenant.Name
        }

        ### Add the users roles and groups in the tenant
        $null = Add-Member -InputObject $MainTenantUser -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name $Tenant.Name -Force -Value (
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Roles   = ($SubTenantUsers | Where-Object UserPrincipalName -like ('{0}*' -f $MainTenantUser.UserPrincipalName.Replace("@", "_")) | Select-Object Roles).Roles
                Groups  = ($SubTenantUsers | Where-Object UserPrincipalName -like ('{0}*' -f $MainTenantUser.UserPrincipalName.Replace("@", "_")) | Select-Object Groups).Groups
            }
        )
    }
}

foreach ($Tenant in $Tenants) {
    $properties += @{
        Name = "$($Tenant.Name) - AADRoles"
        Expression = {($_.($Tenant.Name).'Roles'.'DisplayName' | Sort-Object) -join ', '}
    }
    $properties += @{
        Name = "$($Tenant.Name) - Groups"
        Expression = {($_.($Tenant.Name).'Groups'.'DisplayName' | Sort-Object) -join ', '}
    }
}

$MainTenantUsers | Sort-Object 'DisplayName' | Select-Object $properties |
    Export-Csv -Path "$pathto\output.csv" -Encoding 'UTF8' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What cmdlet is giving you the original object? I assume it is `Get-AzTenant` but we need to be sure. Seems to me that `($_.Name)` instead of `($_.($Tenant.Name)` should be giving you the results you want but is pretty hard to tell without looking at the original object.

Comment: The $Tenants Variable does indeed contain information from the Get-AzTenant function, but the MainTenantUsers is the variable i want the Roles and Groups from, and that one is a mix of data. I have expanded my question with more information, to hopefully be of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by changing the approach i used to create the scriptblocks.

I switched from this:

```
foreach ($Tenant in $Tenants) {
    $properties += @{
        Name = "$($Tenant.Name) - AADRoles"
        Expression = {($_.($Tenant.Name).'Roles'.'DisplayName' | Sort-Object) -join ', '}
    }
    $properties += @{
        Name = "$($Tenant.Name) - Groups"
        Expression = {($_.($Tenant.Name).'Groups'.'DisplayName' | Sort-Object) -join ', '}
    }
}
```

to this:

```
foreach ($Tenant in $Tenants.Name) {
    $properties += @{
        Name = "$Tenant - AADRoles"
        Expression = ([Scriptblock]::Create("(`$_.'$Tenant'.'Roles'.'DisplayName' | Sort-Object) -join ', '"))
    }
    $properties += @{
        Name = "$Tenant - Groups"
        Expression = ([Scriptblock]::Create("(`$_.'$Tenant'.'Groups'.'DisplayName' | Sort-Object) -join ', '"))
    }
}
```